# Perl regex not working

Tags: regex, perl

File mentioned below is used for providing access to code repository.

```
cat /home/user/file
@abc_dev_group = @rel_team ram_ji jack_daniel tom_alter
@DEF_release-25Apr_dev_group= @rel_team  @SDV_dev_group
@Ship_dev_group= udit_srinivasan himanshu_singhal  vishal_tripathi
@Ship_release-15Jan2010_group = @release_team
repo cust
    RW+ dev* = @And_dev_group
@And_dev_group = @rel_team  piyush_rastogi naveen_srivastava arpit_chandra
```

I need to search for *user* in lines that contain string starting with @ and ending with '_dev_group'
For example, `@Ship_dev_group`

Such strings are followed by a space (optional), followed by an equal (=) sign and then user names. Once i search for a given user and find that that particular user is absent, i append that user's name in the line.

I wrote this code below but it doesn't seem to work. Actually it's working for some but failing for others. Tried many different variations but couldn't get it working for all.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my ($FILE, $repo);
my $user_name = "john_doe";
my $input_file = "/home/user/file";
my @repository_list = ("abc", "DEF","Ship", "And");

open (FILE, "<", $input_file) || die "Could not open file [$input_file]: $!";
foreach my $repo (@repository_list) {
    if ( ! grep {/^\@${repo}_dev_group.*$user_name.*/} <FILE> ) {
        system ("sed -i \"s/^\\(\@${repo}_dev_group.*\\)/\\1 $user_name/\" $input_file");
    } else {
        printf "User entry already exists in file $input_file\n";
    }
}
close FILE || die "Could not close file [$input_file]: $!";
```

I also used print statement to see what's going on. It does show the correct (supposedly) regex and it also works on command line (Linux box)(though i know bash and Perl regex behave differently) but it's not working through this script.

**UPDATE:**
The script is now working. :) Please see the lines below where i have added comments:

```
open (FILE, "<", $input_file) || die "Could not open file [$input_file]: $!";
@file = <FILE>; # Read into array
foreach my $repo (@repository_list) {
    if ( ! grep {/^\@${repo}_dev_group.*$user_name.*/} @file ) { # grepped the array @file
        system ("sed -i \"s/^\\(\@${repo}_dev_group.*\\)/\\1 $user_name/\" $input_file");
    } else {
        printf "User entry already exists in file $input_file\n";
    }
}
close FILE || die "Could not close file [$input_file]: $!";
```

Why did it start working now? Why was the earlier approach not working? I'm really confused now.

Comment: I feel it's good to explain why a question was downvoted. It will help me improve.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the culprit: you have to use non-greedy quantifiers: so please use `.*?` instead of `.*`...
For example, in a string like `@And_dev_group = @rel_team  piyush_rastogi naveen_srivastava arpit_chandra`, you have two `and` occurrences, so the greediness of the regex will match as  much as possible, which is not what you want...

Comment: Though i tested your suggestion (and it didn't work), i don't really think this is the reason because my grep expression already specifies anchor (^) and looks for anything between @${repo}_dev_group and $user_name. Even if another @ comes in between, that should not matter.

Answer (score 0):

This will search for a given user name on each line and print the line containing it, and the group of user names associated with that line.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @file = ('@abc_dev_group = @rel_team ram_ji jack_daniel tom_alter',
'@DEF_release-25Apr_dev_group= @rel_team  @SDV_dev_group',
'@Ship_dev_group= udit_srinivasan himanshu_singhal  vishal_tripathi',
'@Ship_release-15Jan2010_group = @release_team',
'repo cust',
'    RW+ dev* = @And_dev_group',
'@And_dev_group = @rel_team  piyush_rastogi naveen_srivastava arpit_chandra');

my $user_name = 'jack_daniel';

my $capture;
foreach (@file){
    print "$_\n" if /\@.*_dev_group\s?=(.*$user_name.*)/g;
    ($capture) = $1;
}
print "$capture\n";
```

prints

Line containing username match:

```
@abc_dev_group = @rel_team ram_ji jack_daniel tom_alter
```

All the user names on that line:

```
 @rel_team ram_ji jack_daniel tom_alter
```

Comment: Thanks but the expression does not matches the first line mentioned above. Also, if i use this expression, i guess i'll have to again apply one more search for the user's name, correct? Can you please tell me what's wrong in the regex that i am using?

Comment: @Technext - From this line, as an example, can you show me exactly what you want to capture in your regex? `@abc_dev_group = @rel_team ram_ji jack_daniel tom_alter john_doe`

Comment: My regex should search for user 'tom_alter' if $user_name is 'tom_alter'. My script is just for providing permission to users while making sure that there is no duplicate entry for that user name in the given line. If the user name is already present, i just skip (no sed operation) while notifying the existence of that user.

Answer (score 0):

```
my @file; #load your file here

@file = ('@abc_dev_group = @rel_team ram_ji jack_daniel tom_alter',
'@DEF_release-25Apr_dev_group= @rel_team  @SDV_dev_group',
'@Ship_dev_group= udit_srinivasan himanshu_singhal  vishal_tripathi',
'@Ship_release-15Jan2010_group = @release_team',
'repo cust',
'    RW+ dev* = @And_dev_group',
'@And_dev_group = @rel_team  piyush_rastogi naveen_srivastava arpit_chandra');

my $user_name = "john_doe";

my @new_file = (); #rewrite lines into this

foreach my $line (@file) {
  if ($line =~ /^\@.+_dev_group\s?=\s?((.+\s?)+)$/) {
    my @users = ();
    push @users, split(/\s+/, $1);
    $line .= " $user_name" unless (grep {$_ eq $user_name} @users);    
  }

  push @new_file, $line;
}
```

.

```
foreach my $line (@new_file) {
  print "$line\n";
}
```

This last piece of code will print:

```
@abc_dev_group = @rel_team ram_ji jack_daniel tom_alter john_doe
@DEF_release-25Apr_dev_group= @rel_team  @SDV_dev_group john_doe
@Ship_dev_group= udit_srinivasan himanshu_singhal  vishal_tripathi john_doe
@Ship_release-15Jan2010_group = @release_team
repo cust
    RW+ dev* = @And_dev_group
@And_dev_group = @rel_team  piyush_rastogi naveen_srivastava arpit_chandra john_doe
```

Comment: Thanks for the time and effort @Filippo. Honestly, i have not tried this but i would appreciate if you could let me know the mistake i am committing in my regex and how to solve it. I would prefer not to create another file.